# Поиск соответствия символов в массиве js

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу найти соответствие символов в массиве `phones.code`?

Строка `+3806` находится в массиве, а `+3810` уже не находится в массиве.

```
var phones = [
  {"country": "UA", "code": "+380"},
  {"country": "RU", "code": "+7"},
  {"country": "MD", "code": "+373"}
];
```

Comment: так, напр. - `if ( phones.findIndex(i => i.code === "+380") != -1 ) { alert('EXISTS!') }`

Comment: _а +3810 уже не находится в массиве_ - потому что ее нет

Comment: _«найти соответствие»_ - что подразумевается результатом этой операции? Вложенный объект / его свойство с подстрокой / значение соотв. свойства / булевое значение / ...?

Comment: Скорее всего выяснилось, что если вводить в инпут больше цифр, чем код, то сам код уже не определяется (из предыдущего вопроса автора). То есть телефон +3806ХХХХХХХХХ соответствует коду +380, а +3810ХХХХХХХ не соответствует ни одному из кодов из массива. Соответственно, нужно определить, есть ли в начале строки какое-либо из соответствий из списка кодов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как знак "+" не должен встречаться где-то, кроме начала телефона, то предлагаю переработать код следующим образом:

```js
var phones = [{
    "country": "UA",
    "code": "+380"
  },
  {
    "country": "RU",
    "code": "+7"
  },
  {
    "country": "MD",
    "code": "+373"
  }
];

document.querySelector('input.phone').addEventListener('keyup', e =>{
        document.querySelector('#country').textContent = 
            phones.find(el => e.target.value.includes(el.code))?.country ?? 'no';
})
```

```html
<span id="country"></span>
<input type="text" class="phone">
```